# DB2 use IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() twice after the initial insert

Tags: db2

Pls help me retrieve IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() into a variable and use it in additional INSERT statements. Following is not working:

```
INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF_GROUP(CONFIG_GROUP_NAME) VALUES('Item1'); --Generates identity OK
SET :IVAR = IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL(); --OK
INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF(GROUP_ID, NAME, CVALUE) VALUES(:IVAR, 'token', ''); --FAILS
INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF(GROUP_ID, NAME, CVALUE) VALUES(:IVAR, 'name', '');
```

Following works but I need to do two INSERTS after retrieving IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()

```
INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF_GROUP(CONFIG_GROUP_NAME) VALUES('Item1'); --OK
INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF(GROUP_ID, NAME, CVALUE) VALUES(IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL(), 'token', ''); --IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() contains a value
INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF(GROUP_ID, NAME, CVALUE) VALUES(IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL(), 'name', ''); --IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() is null
```

Kind regards
A.H.

Comment: What platform and version of DB2?  What's the error message when it fails?  This doesn't look like straight SQL; as it looks like you're using host variables  What language is the SQL embedded in?.

Comment: DB2 9.7 on Windows, SQL edited and run in Control Center. Yes, host variables. I will run these SQLs raw, they will not be embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative could be to do a `SELECT FROM INSERT`.

```
SELECT id
INTO :IVAR
FROM FINAL TABLE (
    INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF_GROUP(CONFIG_GROUP_NAME) VALUES('Item1');
)
```

Here's [an article](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/db2luw/selecting-from-an-insert-update-delete-statement-7239) about the options you have to do a select from INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

Comment: Here you are retrieving identity number. But I have no problem using SET :IVAR = IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL();          It fails on INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF(GROUP_ID, NAME, CVALUE) VALUES(:IVAR, 'token', ''); becouse I use :IVAR in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Are you allowed to use host variables in an plain INSERT statement (see example) running in a query in Control Center?

Answer (score 0):

I got the impression it is not possible to use host variables in dynamic SQL, in Control Center.
So I solved it by using SELECT MAX() since I get nowhere and need a fast workaround. I know it is not bulletproof solution since somebody else may run INSERT in SCH1.CONF_GROUP while INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF is running thus returning a wrong MAX() value. But this script will be running on a new DB via only one DB connection/session so I don't expect erroneous situation to happen.

ex:

```
INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF_GROUP(CONFIG_GROUP_NAME) VALUES('Item1');
INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF(GROUP_ID, NAME, CVALUE) SELECT MAX(CONFIG_GROUP_ID), 'token', '' FROM SCH1.CONF_GROUP;
INSERT INTO SCH1.CONF(GROUP_ID, NAME, CVALUE) SELECT MAX(CONFIG_GROUP_ID), 'name', '' FROM SCH1.CONF_GROUP;
```